# Error in loadNamespace

Tags: r

I got a sudden error in loading packages. I had been able to load same packages before but I am receiving this error one of a sudden. I tried to re-install the packages but still the same errors. Does anybody have any idea?

```
library(minfi)

Loading required package: bumphunter
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘minfi’
```

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bumphunter_1.8.0     locfit_1.5-9.1       iterators_1.0.7      foreach_1.4.2       
 [5] Biostrings_2.36.0    XVector_0.8.0        GenomicRanges_1.20.3 GenomeInfoDb_1.4.0  
 [9] IRanges_2.2.1        S4Vectors_0.6.0      lattice_0.20-31      Biobase_2.28.0      
[13] BiocGenerics_0.14.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] futile.logger_1.4.1     GenomicFeatures_1.20.1  bitops_1.0-6            futile.options_1.0.0   
 [5] tools_3.2.0             rngtools_1.2.4          zlibbioc_1.14.0         biomaRt_2.24.0         
 [9] digest_0.6.8            RSQLite_1.0.0           doRNG_1.6               registry_0.2           
[13] DBI_0.3.1               rtracklayer_1.28.4      stringr_1.0.0           pkgmaker_0.22          
[17] grid_3.2.0              AnnotationDbi_1.30.1    XML_3.98-1.1            BiocParallel_1.2.2     
[21] lambda.r_1.1.7          magrittr_1.5            Rsamtools_1.20.2        codetools_0.2-11       
[25] matrixStats_0.14.0      GenomicAlignments_1.4.1 xtable_1.7-4            stringi_0.4-1          
[29] RCurl_1.95-4.6
```

Comment: Do you have the package `Rcpp` installed? Check by typing `library(Rcpp)`. If this leads to an error message saying that "there is no packge called 'Rcpp'", you should type `install.packages("Rcpp")`.

Comment: since [minfi](http://bioconductor.org/packages/minfi) is a Bioconductor package, use `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("Rcpp")` to install Rcpp; this will ensure that you get the correct version of Rcpp for your version of R / Bioconductor.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very strange because I could load the same packages before and one of a sudden these series of errors appeared for the same packages.